# String.Format Currency for K, M and B

Tags: c#, currency, string.format

If a currency amount is very large, I'm trying to abbreviate it.

For example:

```
   if (amt > 1000000)
   {
       decimal d = (decimal)Math.Round(amt / 1000, 0);
       return String.Format("{0:C0}", d) + " K";
   }
```

If a number is given over 1 million, it will take off the last 3 digits and replace with a K.  Works just fine when the currency symbol (like $ is on the left hand side)

However, some currency symbols get put on the right hand side.

So instead of a nice looking **$100 K** for USD, I'd get **100 € K** for French Euros.

How can I change the format to put the K immediately after the numbers, and before the currency symbol.

Seems like it might be a step too far. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. Got it. You could try `Unicodes` for the currency. Like for Euro it is `u20A0`, and format your `return value`. You will be required to use `switch case` statements for the different currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CurrencyPositivePattern to determine if the currency symbol comes before or after the number.  Then you can modify the CurrencySymbol to suit your needs.

```
        decimal amt = 10000000;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");     //set up France as current culture
        NumberFormatInfo NFI = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

        string currencySymbol =  NFI.CurrencySymbol;
        int currencyPosition = NFI.CurrencyPositivePattern;

        if (amt > 1000000)

        {
        if (currencyPosition == 3)     // n $  
        {
            NFI.CurrencySymbol = "K " + currencySymbol;
        }
            decimal d = (decimal)Math.Round(amt / 1000, 0);
            string output = d.ToString("c");
        }
```

I know this is not the best implementation of a custom number format, but this is just to get the idea across.

See:
[NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a class with the IFormatProvider like this

```
public class MoneyFormat: IFormatProvider,  ICustomFormatter
        {
            public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
            {
                if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
                    return this;
                else
                    return null;
            }

            public string Format(string fmt, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
            {
                if (arg.GetType() != typeof(decimal))
                    try
                    {
                        return HandleOtherFormats(fmt, arg);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new FormatException(string.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid", fmt), e);
                    }

                string ufmt = fmt.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (!(ufmt == "K"))
                    try
                    {
                        return HandleOtherFormats(fmt, arg);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new FormatException(string.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid", fmt), e);
                    }

                decimal result;
                if (decimal.TryParse(arg.ToString(), out result))
                {
                    if (result >= 1000000)
                    {
                        decimal d = (decimal)Math.Round(result / 10000, 0);

                        CultureInfo clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
                        string oldCurrSymbol = clone.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
                        clone.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";

                        return String.Format(clone, "{0:C0}", d).Trim() + " K" + oldCurrSymbol;
                    }
                }
                else
                    return string.Format("{0:C0}", result) + " K";
            }

            private string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg)
            {
                if (arg is IFormattable)
                    return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                else if (arg != null)
                    return arg.ToString();
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
}
```

Then you can call it in your format like so:

```
return string.Format( new MoneyFormat(), "{0:K}", amt);
```

You can then tweek the way you want to represent your "K" or other reference symbols that you want to add

CultureInfo("fr-fr") : 100 K€

CultureInfo("en-us") : 100 K$

CultureInfo("ru-RU") : 100 Kр.

Comment: I use the IFormatProvider alot, to handle special string format that I want to implement.